# Añadir agrupación en consulta sparql

Tags: sql

Primero de todo perdonad si ya hay algo parecido, pero no he conseguido encontrarlo y soy bastante novata con las consultas sparql.

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en dbpedia, intento sacar todas las películas protagonizadas por kevin bacon y obtengo el listado, pero me aparecen duplicadas.
Es decir la pelicula nixon, que si aparece kevin bacon, me aparece con el resto de actores.

¿Cómo podría quedarme únicamente con la línea película-actor = kevin bacon?

Mi consulta en https://dbpedia.org/sparql/

```
SELECT ?film ?starring
     WHERE {
      ?film rdf:type dbo:Film . 
      ?film dbo:starring ?starring;  
         dbo:starring dbr:Kevin_Bacon .
```

Mi resultado:

```
|index|film|starring|
|---|---|---|
|0|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Frost/Nixon_(film)|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Michael_Sheen|
|1|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Frost/Nixon_(film)|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Rebecca_Hall|
|2|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Frost/Nixon_(film)|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Oliver_Platt|
|3|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Frost/Nixon_(film)|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Sam_Rockwell|
|4|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Frost/Nixon_(film)|http://dbpedia\.org/resource/Kevin_Bacon|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ?f 
WHERE {
?f rdf:type dbo:Film .
?f dbo:starring dbr:Kevin_Bacon.
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, aunque esa la probé, pero solo me devuelve 0,1,2,3,4 y necesito las películas.

Comment: ¿En Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI) tienes "http://dbpedia.org"? A mi me está devolviendo todas las películas: https://tinyurl.com/ypc95xrt

Comment: pues hubiera jurado que si! pero efectivamente, ahora si las muestra. mil gracias!